# Why do I see this error printing from a .NET app on Citrix?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, crystal-reports-2010

We have a .NET application (in-house built) that prints using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010. It runs in a Citrix XenApp context. If we run an on-screen report, using the Crystal Reports WPF viewer control, we see the report as expected. However, if we then click the Printer icon within the CR WPF viewer, we get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while getting the default printer.
Win32 error: The system cannot find the file specified.
System.Printing
at System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDataFromServer(String property, Boolean forceRefresh)
at System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.get_DefaultPrintQueue()
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.PrintControl.ShowPrintDialog()
at SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ReportAlbum.PrintReport()
```